# How to load data into a database of MarkLogic using java?

Tags: java, marklogic

I have a sample java program can does some tasks and generates a `List<String>`. I have the result, let's say in a variable `result` of type `List<String>`. I would like to send the result to a MarkLogic remote server using `xcc`. I remember there's a way. All i know is I'll have to download `xcc` jar into my java project and an `xdbc` port in MarkLogic but do not know how to code it in java. Need help!

Comment: Have you, y'know, actually tried anything?

Comment: @Michael - I'm meanwhile going through manuals.

Comment: MarkLogic offers free developer training for building Java apps, but you will probably need to brush up on Java first. 
 https://www.marklogic.com/learn/courses/developing-marklogic-apps-java/

Answer (score 1):

[MarkLogic has a Java Client API](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java). I'd encourage you to look into that, rather than XCC. As Michael pointed out, there is a [Developing MarkLogic Apps in Java course](https://www.marklogic.com/learn/courses/developing-marklogic-apps-java/) available from MarkLogic University (free, available online). If you haven't already taken it, I'd encourage you to take the MarkLogic Fundamentals course, which is available free as either instructor-led or self-paced.

This training will show you how to insert data into MarkLogic and how to query it.

For those who already know the fundamentals and are experienced with Java, the documentation discusses how to [create single documents](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/document-operations#id_50917), how to [create multiple documents synchronously](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/bulk#id_74386), and how to [create multiple documents asynchronously](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/data-movement#id_72824).